# Part of SIGCHLD not coming to signalfd

Tags: c, linux, process

the master process starts the processes proc1, proc2, proc3. creating a signalfd for SIGCHLD in non-blocking mode.
I kill child processes through your text `pkill proc`.  Then different situations happen, from signalfd it is possible to read either 1 or 2 signals (the second signal reads after entering poll).

where is the third signal?

I don't understand what to try.  no signal coming to fd?

Comment: We can't see your code — that makes it hard to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> where is the third signal?

It's impossible to know from your description alone exactly what is happening, but very likely you're running into the fact that signals of the same type do not queue.  For example, only one `SIGCHLD` can be pending for a given process at a time.  If a second comes in while one is already pending, then one of the two is dropped.

Comment: If OP wants to be certain that the problem is not multiple signals at once, I recommend using a mutex to ensure only one process is signalling at a time. (E.G. a child takes the semaphore before death, and the main process releases after processing the signal)

It is also possible that the main process is quitting after the third process is killed. Without more code I cannot be certain. In that case, the main thread will not receive the signal because it has already finished.